# How to bind object from databse only with id in asp .net mvc?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, model-binding

I'm currently creating a asp .net mvc website who use a many-to-many relationship between these two entities:

```
public class MasterCode{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string libelle { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Product> products { get; set; }
}

public class Product{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<MasterCode> masterCodes { get; set; }
}
```

The entities are actually (a lot) more complex but this is to show how it work.
 my problem is: on my Product's create/edit view, i want to put a list of hidden fields with the existing Product's MasterCode's ids. These fields change with a serie of ajax queries during the user's input.
But when i try to bind the complete Product in my action, it doesn't work because the binded Mastercodes only contains the ids (which is problematic due to the invalid ModelState plus i don't want to erase the Mastercode's datas).

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,name,masterCode")] Product product)
{
    /*Wrong because the mastercodes only contains their ids*/
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        /*...*/
    }
    return View(product);
}
```

How can i automatically bind the Mastercodes data from Entity Framework only with their id?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: As always, use a view model.

Comment: I don't understand how a viewmodel can help me here?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Comment: Because a view model will only have `IList<int> products` because you only want the ID of each product and you will not get any issues with validation.

Comment: In your edit view, the user can edit the mastercodes of the a given products ?

Comment: No they can't. Only the administrators can edit the master codes. The user can only select which mastercodes the product have.